# Java XML Validation against XSD does not throw errors in specific cases

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I´m looking for an answer for this problem quite a while now but I have´nt really found anything for this problem.

So I want to validate a XML-File against a XSD Schema File using the Java XML Validation Validator. It already works. But, at specific cases, the validator seems to ignore errors in the XML File.

The Validator throws an error if, for example, in the following bit of an xml file the "strasse" tag is misspelled as "strass"

But if I change the tag "hausnummer" to "hausnumme" the validation shows no errors.

```
            <adresse>
                <strasse>Finsterwalderstraße</strasse>
                <hausnummer>7</hausnummer>
                <hausnummerzusatz></hausnummerzusatz>
                <plz>83026999</plz>
                <ort>Rosenheim</ort>
            </adresse>
```

I believe the reason that the second case was ignored is that the third tag "hausnummerzusatz" is marked as optional in the xsd. I confirmed that with trying the same with different tags that before optional tags.

For Validation I use this methods.
The initialization of the validator object

```
private Validator initializeSchemaValidator() throws SAXException {
    Validator schemaValidator = this.schema.newValidator();
    schemaValidator.setErrorHandler(this);
    return schemaValidator;
}
```

The implementations of the ErrorHandler

```
@Override
public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
    Message message = addMessage(e, MessageSeverity.ERROR);
    LOGGER.error(message.toString());
}
```

same for warning and fatal_error.

And the validate method itself

```
public List<Message> validate() throws IOException {
    try {
        validator.validate(jaxbSource);
    }
    catch (SAXException ex) {
        ...
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(validationMessages);
}
```

If I validate the XML while unmarshalling, using the setSchema() Method of the unmarshaller, I do get an error. But I dont want to use the unmarshaller for validating.

Has anybody experienced this problem too or is there a way to tell the validator to be more strict when validating?

Edit: The whole XSD is a bit too big to post here, so I´ll just post the part that is relevent to the example above.

The header:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ka="http://www.g-fit.de/ngs/kundenauftrag" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:voi="http://www.g-fit.de/ngs/kundenauftrag/voice" xmlns:ip="http://www.g-fit.de/ngs/kundenauftrag/ip_nga" targetNamespace="http://www.g-fit.de/ngs/kundenauftrag" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" jxb:version="2.0">
```

The definition of the adresse type:

```
<xs:complexType name="adresse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="strasse" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="hausnummer" type="ka:hausnummer"/>
        <xs:element name="hausnummerzusatz" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="plz" type="ka:plz"/>
        <xs:element name="ort" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Camn't answer this without seeing your XSD.

Comment: Ok i added the part of the xsd that is relevent to the example I´ve posted.

Comment: Can't explain that. Try posting a repro so we can try it for ourselves.